# How to find the the inferred type of a variable in swift 2.1?

Tags: swift2

Is there a function which to return the inferred type of a variable/constant in Swift 2.1? In the example below I would like to know what type is getting the "x" variable:

```
var x = false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `.dynamicType` suffix:

```
var x = false
print(x.dynamicType) // "Bool.Type"
```

If you want to know and make use of the type during runtime, you can store the value of `x` in a variable of type `Any`, and infer the type of by a `switch` case on the `Any` variable.

```
var x = false
let xAny : Any = x

switch xAny {
case is Int: print("x is an integer")
case is Double: print("x is a double")
case is String: print("x is a string")
case is Bool: print("x is a boolean")
case _: print("x is of unknown type")
} /* prints "x is a boolean" */
```